# How to pack blobstorage with Plone and RelStorage

Tags: postgresql, plone, blobstorage, relstorage

I have run zodbpack on my local build and reduced my data.fs and blobstorage significantly (like to <50%).

When i run zodbpack on the test server the postgres 'zodb' database packs and comes down in size, but the blobstorage doesnt budge in size.

I've tried running it with every combo of

blob-dir /mnt/drbd/blobstorage

I can think of, but it doesnt budge.

Can it be packed?

RelStorage = 1.5.1

I'm considering upgarding RelStorage to 1.6.0, not sure if that will help.

**Update:**

Now running relstorage locally, I also see the same behaviour... database packs, blobs don't clean up.

`$ bin/zodbpack -d 7 zodbpack-conf.xml`

zodbpack-conf.xml

```
<relstorage>

pack-gc false

blob-dir /Users/aaron/Development/restores/blobstorage

<postgresql>

dsn dbname='zodb' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='password'

</postgresql>

</relstorage>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I never used RelStorage, but the the zodbpack script does not touch the blobs (According what I read in the documentation). So I guess the your Postgres has it's own blobs?

Comment: I have no problem having RelStorage zodbpack clean up deleted blobs using blob-storage directory and shared-blob = on -- can you elaborate on your zope.conf configuration and where you are storing your blobs?  Also, if you are storing blobs on disk, du -hs your blobstorage/0x00 directory, and your blobstorage/tmp directory.

Comment: @sdupton Just tried it again... database comes down, blob don't budge. Will update the question with my config also ^

Comment: "packing" means foremost to delete the modification-history, a.k.a versioning, of content-objects, which BLOBs ("Binary large objects") don't have, not being content modifiable by users, but mere files (Images, PDF's, etc.). So to me trying to pack BLOBs doesn't make sense, meaning you cannot reduce the size of BLOBs, if that's what you ment.